# Use FMDB for SQLite library how automatic update tableview like controllerDidChangeContent of Core Data

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, fmdb

i'm using core data in my app, but i notice that is a bit slow and i have some crash of problems of inconsistency, maybe i have bad managed it, however i want pass to `SQLite` and i found the `FMDB` library, but my question is how i can automatically update a tableview when i made background change in the database? using the core data there is the `NSFetchedController` and in particular there is the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` to automatic refresh the table view, how i can perform this using the SQLite?

Comment: After change in DB call `[tableView relodData];`. Or you are making changes in DB outside of app?

Comment: No i make the call in a background thread in the app...

Comment: then create Notification. Which will fire when background thread complete and in that Notification method call `[tableView relodData];` to reload data in tableView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NSNotificationCenter` for that, Here is the code sample..

In your TableViewController.m file add this code

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadTableView:) name:@"ReloadTableView" object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)reloadTableView:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [tableView relodData];
}
```

And where you call your background thread, put this code in its completion.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ReloadTableView" object:nil];
```